# how to get controller and action name from RewriteContext

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

having a rewrite rule like this:

```
public class MyRule : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        ///var controllerName = ???
    }
}
```

how do I get the controller and action name ?

---

in Startup.cs /Configure I have:

```
var rewriter = new RewriteOptions().Add(new MyRule());

app.UseRewriter(rewriter);

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(
...
```

Comment: Rule wont know anything about the controller and action. Way too early in the pipeline to know anything about routing.

Comment: Reference [URL Rewriting Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @Nikosi sound right, I was using a global action filter in mvc5 to redirect from `contr/actnAme` to `Contr/ActName`, thought that in core this is done using the rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite Rules wont know anything about the controller and action.

It is way too early in the pipeline to know anything about MVC routing and is usually associated with rewriting to resources based on a pattern defined for the request.

> URL rewriting is the act of modifying request URLs based on one or more predefined rules. URL rewriting creates an abstraction between resource locations and their addresses so that the locations and addresses aren't tightly linked.
>   URL rewriting is valuable in several scenarios to:
>
> - Move or replace server resources temporarily or permanently and maintain stable locators for those resources.
> - Split request processing across different apps or across areas of one app.
> - Remove, add, or reorganize URL segments on incoming requests.
> - Optimize public URLs for Search Engine Optimization (SEO).
> - Permit the use of friendly public URLs to help visitors predict the content returned by requesting a resource.
> - Redirect insecure requests to secure endpoints.
> - Prevent hotlinking, where an external site uses a hosted static asset on another site by linking the asset into its own content.

Reference [URL Rewriting Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2)